# Will changing an events Time-Zone affect other people on shared events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ekevent

If I were to normalize an `EKEvent` 's startDate property using a `NSDateFormatter` and setting the time zone with

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

 event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [event.startDate]]];
```

and I later make a change to that event requiring me to call

```
[self.event.eventStore saveEvent:currentEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
```

Would it override the time-zone on the server, causing issues for the person (whom uses GCal) in another state that originally created that shared calendar event, or is it just a local change?

If it does affect the event, what is the best way for me to make sure the events on the app side always represent the users current time zone, without having to change format the event each time I refer to it on the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the timezone of an event will sync. If an event happens at 9 Mountain time, the event will be displayed as occurring at 9 to anyone whos devices general setiings is set to mountain time. If their device is eastern time, the event will appear to occur at 7. If you change the time zone of the event to Eastern, devices in mountain time will now see the event occurring at 11, and eastern time devices will see the event occurring at 9. So, changing the time zone does not change the time it occurs in its own time zone, but it will change it relative to where you moved it from.

You can do 2 things after asking the user when the event occurs: 1) you can assume the event occurs in the users devices current time zone. 2) you can ask them where the event occurs and set the events time zone to that.

If you have an event with the wrong time, you should first set its time zone to where the event is actually happening, then change when it occurs to when it actually happens, where it actually happens.

If you just focus on getting the data on the event set correctly, it will appear correctly on everyones device who is sharing the calendar with you.

Comment: If the EKEvent.startDate and endDate properties both fall on the same day in both time zones and I change the endDate (forward a few hours) and it still resides on the same day in my time zone but falls onto the following day for the other users calendar, will it show on his calendar as crossing the two days? I am assuming the time-zone on the server takes care of that?

Comment: To clarify, it *should* show up on the other users calendar on the following and not on the same day in the morning? Such as changing a NSDate to 11:00 PM Tuesday on my calendar and I expect it to be 3:00 AM Wednesday on his calendar, it will show up as such and NSDate will not wrap to 3:00 AM Tuesday?

Comment: If you want the event to start at a specific time like 9 AM regardless of the time zone set the date to 9 AM in the system time zone and then set the timeZone property to nil. Have a look at EKEvent's documentation about the timeZone property.

Comment: You are correct, if the event timezone is set to your time zone (it will occur location-wise in your timezone) with an endDate of 11pm, if the other person is 4 hours ahead of you, it will appear on his calendar as ending at 3am the next day.

Comment: Setting the timezone to nil for shared calendars seems like a bad idea. Setting the timezone property to nil should only be done on events on my personal calendar, because in my opinion, if i go on vacation in a different time zone, its confusing and somewhat startling to see all of my events that happen after i get home "shift" by a few hours. Id prefer my events look like they would if i were back home. In this case setting the event timeZone property to nil can make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification everyone. I will just set the time zone of the event's start and end dates to the system time zone then and leave it at that. I don't really see a need to set the event property's timezone to nil.